# python executing in IDLE, but not in termnal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, executable, sensors

I have a python script on a Raspberry Pi reading the temperature and humidity from a sensor. It works fine when started in IDLE, but when I try starting it in a terminal I get the message:`sudo: unable to execute .thermostaatgui.py: No such file or directory`. The first line in the script is: `#! /usr/bin/python`, the same as in other scripts that run without problems and the script is made executable with chmod +x.

In the script Adafruit_DHT, datetime and time are imported, other scripts that work do the same.

Comment: Specify the script's full path or first make it the working directory through `cd`.

Comment: Here is  the command and the output:

Comment: Here is  the command and the output: "pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples $ sudo ./thermostaatgui.py 
sudo: unable to execute ./thermostaatgui.py: No such file or directory". The script is in the directory, other scripts in the same directory that import Adafruit_DHT do run without problems.

Comment: As a workaround, I copied the contents of "thermostaatgui.py" over the contents of a working script ("mysimpletest.py"), saved it and it runs OK. @nos: it needs to run as the root user because it uses the Raspberry GPIO pins (according to the Adafruit people)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, still a little puzzled why it happened, but anyway this solved the problem:
As a workaround, I copied the contents of "thermostaatgui.py" over the contents of a working script ("mysimpletest.py"), saved it and it runs OK.

Answer (score 1):

+1 on the above solution.

To Debug
try this
Type "pwd" on your terminal. This will tell you where you are in the shell. 
Then type "ls -lah" and look for your script. if you can not find it, then you need to "cd" to the directory where the script exists and then execute the script

Comment: That 's not the problem: 
"pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples $ ls -lah
total 56K
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4.0K Jan  9 09:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 pi pi 4.0K Jan  3 15:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 2.3K Jan  3 13:46 AdafruitDHT.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 5.5K Jan  3 13:46 google_spreadsheet.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 1.8K Jan  5 22:16 mijntest.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 2.0K Jan  3 13:46 simpletest.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  14K Jan  9 09:42 temp-hum2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  115 Jan 10 22:54 temp-hum.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 4.2K Jan 10 22:55 thermostaatgui.py"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have just made a typo:

```
sudo .thermostaatgui.py
```

should probably be

```
sudo ./thermostaatgui.py
```

assuming that you're in the directory containing your script, and that it's called `thermostaatgui.py`.

Comment: Not a typo, it is "thermostaat" in dutch. But appreciate your comment